# Disable form field when another is unchecked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, html-helper

I have a asp.net mvc website and a form.

For the form, I essentially use :

```
 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Field)
 @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Field)
```

But I have some boolean fields that are linked to another one. So I would like to disable these fields when the other one is unchecked.

I also use Jquery mobile so it's generating [these kind of checkboxes](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-checkboxes.html)

So I don't have the Id of the generated checkbox...

Is there a way to do what I need using these HTML helpers or do I have to creates my fields manually ?

Comment: Not clear what you mean. The link you included has `id` attributes for the checkboxes. Which fields do you want to disable - one of them, all of them? and when are they disabled - when one particular checkbox is unchecked or any of them are unchecked?

Comment: If use the the Html helper, I don't know how to get the Id. I have 5 boolean fields, when I uncheck the first one, I would like to uncheck the four others and disable the fields. I could resolve the problem by adding the checkboxes manually, but I would like to know if it's possible to do it using the Html helper

Comment: `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MyProperty)` will render a checkbox with `id="MyProperty"` so it should be easy enough to use jquery selectors for what you want but its a little hard to tell without seeing the html. Even without the `id` you could use `$(input[type="checkbox"]').first()` to get the first checkbox